# KNN Imputation: Do you use the training preProcess on both training and test sets?

Tags: r, data-imputation, caret, k-nearest-neighbour

I understand that you want to impute missing values separately for `training`, `testing`, and `validation` datasets because you don't want the testing or validation data to influence the training dataset.

But if I use the `caret` package to do the following

```
train_pre_obj <- preProcess(training, method = "knnImpute", k = 10)
training2 <- predict(train_pre_obj, training)
```

do I use `train_pre_obj` to also fill in the missing values for the `testing` and `validation` datasets  or do I create a `test_pre_obj` and then a `val_pre_obj` function and apply that to the `testing` and `validation` sets, respectively?

Typed a little differently, should it be:

```
train_pre_obj <- preProcess(training, method = "knnImpute", k = 10)
training2 <- predict(train_pre_obj, training)
testing2 <- predict(train_pre_obj, testing)
validation2 <- predict(train_pre_obj, validation)
```

OR

```
train_pre_obj <- preProcess(training, method = "knnImpute", k = 10)
training2 <- predict(train_pre_obj, training)

test_pre_obj <- preProcess(testing, method = "knnImpute", k = 10)
testing2 <- predict(test_pre_obj, testing)

val_pre_obj <- preProcess(validation, method = "knnImpute", k = 10)
validation2 <- predict(val_pre_obj, validation)
```

I feel like the difference between the two approaches would be that the first approach would center and scale all values for the testing and validation datasets based on the non-missing values from the training set, while the second approach would center and scale each respective dataset's values based on their own non-missing values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your should be using the training data preprocessing model to do the predictions on the test dataset. Leave the validation dataset as it is, because it is to be considered completely new data for your machine learning model.
As far as the test data is concerned, if you build a seperate model of pre-processing on the test dataset, you are kind of using the test data also to train your model, and that is known to be over-fitting of the model